# Error While deploying a project from CVS in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, struts, cvs

I am using Eclipse 6.6 and working on struts framework in java. I have imported a context from CVS and when I am trying to run the application it is showing the following error.
But when I do the same in the other systems its working fine. Please help me with this

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Parsing error processing resource path 
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.handleConfigException(ActionServlet.java:1035)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.parseModuleConfigFile(ActionServlet.java:1014)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModuleConfig(ActionServlet.java:955)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:470)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1002)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely missing a config file. Might be the main struts config file. Look in the web.xml file for the struts filter or servlet and see if it's parametrized with a certain config file and then check if that file exists in your project in the right location. If there's no config file explicitly defined, then it's using the default one, namely struts.xml which should be in the root of the classpath, so check if that exists.

Comment: Yes, The struts config file is present in web-inf folder and also configured in web.xml. And when  I import the same context from cvs in other systems its working fine. But Only in my system its giving an exception.

Answer (score 0):

There also be a reason that the struts(version).jar is not matching with the DTD. Check the jars on the machine its working after checkout from the CVS.

If its same as on ther machine its working fine then Please try to put struts.jar in your classpath in your menifest file.